# Typescript: Type `T` does not satisfy the constraint `object`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

After installing a package and its `@types` package. I've started facing this issue here for the following code:

[image]

Here's the error:

[image]

I actually installed `react-draft-wysiwyg` and its types, and after that, this already existing code started throwing error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, The Record type takes 2 arguments

```js
type RecordType<K, T> = Record<K, T>; // this maybe the definition that you want
type MaybeRecord<K, T> = T | RecordType<K, T>;
```

Replicating the same error on typescriptplayground, I got the error similar to
`Generic type 'Record' requires 2 type argument(s).` Rather than the one mentioned.

Comment: I think there's a version mismatch @charanpreet? I'm getting some other issue actually: `Generic type 'Record<TProps>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

Comment: My TS version is `4.1.3`.

Comment: The definition contains the two types since [ver2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type). Maybe there is a type declaration that overrides it ? Having a little hard time replicating it, could you setup a codesandbox/stackblitz/replit/codespace for the same ?

Comment: Thanks Charantpreet for helping, I dived deeper and it turned out that the issue is related to the `immutable` package. Really thanks for helping. 

Comment: Just to be complete, was it the immer package or some other one that comes with redux ?

Comment: Oh no! No redux. I don't rely on redux at all, just the `context` concept. Thanks for you curiosity.

Comment: It was actually an issue related to the `immutable` package getting updated. The recent packages installed in the project actually ended up updating that package.